# Polymer google-map-directions - using latlng for end-address

Tags: google-maps, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am triyng to use `latlng` for `google-map-directions` polymer element. If I just put in a string, such as `Austin` it works and there are directions. But if I try `new google.maps.LatLng(29.520332, -98.431211)` there are no directions. To be clear, there are no errors ether.

In the template I outputted `{{endingAddress}}` which it did successfully output a string `( ...., ....)`, so the databinding is correct and working.

Any suggestions?

```
    <div id="map-container">
        <google-map latitude="29.520332" longitude="-98.431211" 
          api-key='AIzaXjfkwM'
          fit-to-markers>
          <google-map-marker latitude="29.520332" longitude="-98.431211"
            title="wedding location"></google-map-marker>
        </google-map>
        <google-map-directions
          api-key='AICpwM'
          start-address="Austin"
          end-address$="{{endingAddress}}"></google-map-directions>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'map-wedding',
      properties: {
        endingAddress: {
          type: Object
        }
      },
      attached: function () {
        var gMap = document.querySelector('google-map');
        gMap.addEventListener('api-load', function(e) {
          document.querySelector('google-map-directions').map = this.map;
          this.endingAddress =  new google.maps.LatLng(29.520332, -98.431211);
        }.bind(this));
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map?active=google-map-directions), the `start-address` and `end-address` properties can take in an address or a lat/long as a `String`. You need to link your `google-map` to your `google-map-directions` element using the `map` attribute on both elements.

Here is a simple code example I have used to get this working:

```
<dom-module id="map-test">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }

      google-map {
        height: 600px;
      }
    </style>

    <google-map-directions
      start-address="Austin" end-address="29.520332,-98.431211" map="{{map}}"></google-map-directions>
    <google-map latitude="29.520332" longitude="-98.431211" fit-to-markers map="{{map}}">
      <google-map-marker latitude="29.520332" longitude="-98.431211" title="wedding location"></google-map-marker>
    </google-map>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "map-test"
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Make sure you are including both `google-map` and `google-map-directions` elements too.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing 2 things wrong.... first was I was using parenthesis in `end-address="(29.520332,-98.431211)"` when it should of been just `end-address="29.520332,-98.431211"`.

I was using the wrong closure when I binded `this` in the handler:

```
    gMap.addEventListener('api-load', function(e) {
      document.querySelector('google-map-directions').map = this.map;
      this.endingAddress =  new google.maps.LatLng(29.520332, -98.431211);
    }.bind(this));
```

Once I removed `this` binding in the handler and used:

```
    gMap.addEventListener('api-load', function(e) {
      document.querySelector('google-map-directions').map = this.map;
      this.endingAddress =  new google.maps.LatLng(29.520332, -98.431211);
    });
```

It worked. With the wrong closure, `document.querySelector('google-map-directions').map = this.map;` was getting a different map object.